# Finding Density From Expected Value

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics

Problem:
Given that $X \sim N(0,1)$, let $Y = e^{X}$. Find a formula for the density, $f_{Y}(y)$.

Progress:
Using the Law of the Unconscious Statistician, I computed
$$E[Y] = E[e^{X}] = \sqrt{e}.$$

I figured that a potential solution had to satisfy both:
$$\int_{\mathrm{R}} f_{Y}(y) \, dy = 1$$
$$\int_{\mathrm{R}} yf_{Y}(y) \, dy = \sqrt{e}$$

I tried playing around with integration by parts on the second one but realized that wasn't going to get me anywhere because I can't find $f'$ or $\int f \, dy$.

---

Now that I'm typing it out, maybe I can make integration by parts work using
$$F(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{t} f_{Y}(t) \, dt$$

If anyone has some insight that would be really helpful. I'm probably on the wrong track but I'm gonna go play around with this some more.

Comment: The density for $X$ has a factor of $\sqrt{2\pi}^{-1}$ in front of it. The integral you listed evaluates to $\sqrt{2e\pi}$. Division gives what I put. I think anyways.

Comment: The guy I replied to deleted his comment I think. Oh well.

Comment: You cannot pretend to find out a density only by knowing the expectation. You _must_ use the information that $X$ is gaussian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F_{Y}(y) = \mathbb{P}\left(e^{X} \leq y\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(X \leq \ln y\right) = F_{X}(\ln y) = \Phi\circ\ln (y)$.

By chain rule, $f_{Y}(y) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\left(\Phi\circ\ln (y)\right) = \Phi^{\prime}\circ\ln(y)\:\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\ln y = \frac{\phi\circ\ln(y)}{y} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln y\right)^{2}}}{y}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. A lot better than where I was trying to go with this.

Comment: I think you want $f_Y(y)$ in the second line.

Comment: It might not be simpler, but  $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln y\right)^{2}} =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y^{\log_e y}}}$

Comment: @JPelter: Welcome :) btw, finding density (more information) from expectation (less information) is usually impossible. If you are satisfied with the answer, please feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

For any differentiable and monotonic (hence invertible) function $Y=g(X)$ we have the [relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables)

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{f_X(x)}{|g'(x)|}=\frac{f_X(g^{-1}(y))}{|g'(g^{-1}(y))|}$$

In our case, $g^{-1}(y) = \log Y$. Hence

$$ f_Y(y) = \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\frac{1}{e^x}=\frac{e^{-(\log y)^2/2}}{y \sqrt{2 \pi}} = \frac{y^{-\log(y)/2-1}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \hspace{1cm} y> 0$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
f_Y(y) & = \frac d {dy} \Pr(Y\le y) = \frac d {dy} \Pr(e^X \le y) = \frac d {dy} \Pr(X \le \log y) = \frac d {dy} F_X(\log y) \\[10pt]
& \underbrace{{} = f_X(\log y) \cdot \frac d {dy} \log y}_\text{chain rule} {} = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(\log y)^2/2} \cdot \frac 1 y.
\end{align}